# GoogleDNSでお名前.comで取得したURLを使う

Tags: dns, google-cloud-dns

[GoogleAPI千本ノック] Google Cloud DNS API を試してみた
http://www.apps-gcp.com/google-cloud-dns-api/

こちらを参考にまったく同じ手順でやっているんですが、どうしてもエラーが出ます。

> DNS ルックアップでエラーが発生したため、hoge.net にあるサーバーを見つけることができません。
>   DNSは、ウェブサイトの名前をインターネット アドレスに変換するためのウェブ
>   サービスです。このエラーはほとんどの場合、インターネットに接続されていないか、ネットワークの設定が間違っていることが原因です。ただし、DNS
>   サーバーの応答がない、ファイアウォールによって Google Chrome からのネットワーク
>   アクセスがブロックされている、などの原因で発生する場合もあります。

Nginxでやっていますが設定は正しいと思います。
Nginxで元のIPを設定すると普通にWordPressが表示されます。
Wordpressには`define('WP_HOME','http://hoge.net');`など正しく設定しています。
24時間待っても変わりません。
Chromeキャッシュクリア、ルーター、回線装置、PC再起動、DNSキャッシュクリアなどあらゆる方法は試してあります。
また、別のURL(hoge2.com)でやっても同じ感じなエラーがでます。

Comment: お使いのプロバイダがgoogle pubic DNSへのアクセスをブロックしているように思いますが。nslookupでserver 8.8.8.8やってからクエリ出すとどうなりますか？

Comment: この質問はGoogle App Engineではなく、google-cloud-dns の質問だと思います。日本語版スタックオーバーフローでは、まだtagが無いので、誰かにtagを作ってもらう必要がありそうです。

Comment: ChromeのシークレットモードでDNSキャッシュが無い状態だとどうなりますか？ あと、質問から読み取れなかったので確認したいのですが、お使いのクライアントのOSは何ですか？クライアントOSに設定しているDNSサーバーご自宅用のルータのIPですか？

Comment: 8.8.8.8　8.8.4.4済みです。
tagの件、気をつけます
シークレットモードでもダメでした。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

解決済みのようですが、一般的な DNSの切り分けについて書きます。
重要なメールが迷惑メールと判断されていたのは不幸なことですが、切り分けが出来ていれば問題解決を早めることが出来たかもしれません。

## WHOIS情報の確認

WHOISで `hoge.net` を検索して ネームサーバーが Google の物になっているか

1. [確認ツール](http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools)の「WHOIS/IPWHOIS Lookup」にドメイン名を入力
2. `dns.managedZones.create` が返した `nameServers` が「Discovered Nameservers」のところに 表示されるか

- 表示されない→レジストラ(お名前.com)のネームサーバーの変更がうまくいってません。

## DNSサーバーへの問合せ

DNSサーバーへの問合せは次の3パターン実施します。

- 権威サーバーへの問合せ → `nameServers` のどれか一つのサーバーに接続
- 公開されたDNSへの問合せ → 例えば Google Public DNS (8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4)に接続
- ローカルネットワーク上のDNSへ問合せ → ご自身のローカルネットワーク内のDNSサーバー

1. nslookup コマンドで DNS問合せを実施

   - コマンド: `nslookup -q=ns ドメイン名 DNSサーバー(ホスト名orIP)`
   - 例) `nslookup -q=ns hoge.net 8.8.8.8`
2. `Non-authoritative answer:` のところに `nameServers` のホスト名が表示されるか

- 権威サーバーからの応答が正しくない場合→Google API側の問題の可能性がある
- 公開されたDNSサーバーからの応答が正しくない場合→レジストラのネームサーバー変更が滞っている可能性がある
- ローカルネットワークのDNSからの応答が正しくない場合→DNSキャッシュが残っておりクリアされていない

## ローカルネットワークのDNSのキャッシュをクリア

クライアントが参照しているDNSサーバーのキャッシュが古いままの場合は、DNSサーバーを再起動します。

## パソコンのDNSキャッシュをクリア

Windowsでは `ipconfig` コマンドを使ってDNSキャッシュをクリアする

1. ローカルPCでコマンドプロンプト or ターミナルを開く
2. ipconfig コマンドで クリア

   - コマンド: `ipconfig /flushdns`
3. もう一度 nslookup で確認する

## Firefoxのプライベートウィンドウ/Chromeのシークレットモード

ブラウザは独自にキャッシュするのであえてキャッシュが無い状態にする。
Firefoxの場合は「プライベートウィンドウ」といいChromeの場合は「シークレットモード」にします。

Comment: Firefoxのプライベートウィンドウ以外全て試していました。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

I CANNは表示されていなかったのですが、お名前.comの登録情報（他経営情報全部）に正しい住所と名前電話番号を記述するとメールが来て制限が解除されたときました。

制限がかかっていたのを知らなかったためこのような結果に至りましたが、お名前.comから来るメールの量は半端無く、ネームサーバや登録情報など変更しただけで全ドメインの10件以上もメールが送信されます。

あまりにもメールが多かったためにGoogleメールにレジストラ情報制限メールが迷惑メールとして判断されたために気づきませんでした。

制限がかかっているのなら、お名前.comホームページにログインした際どこかに制限がかかっていると明白に記述してあるべきだと思いました。

落ち度は楽天並にメールのあるGMOにあると思いました。